# DropdownButton (when I run the app I have error in dropdownbutton)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
 body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          items: ["bad ", "good ", "ok", "sad", "happy"]
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("$e"),
                    value: e,
                  ))
              .toList(),
              onChanged: (val){},
          value: selectedfeeling,
        ),
      ),
```

This is the error:

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 882 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: good. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Either zero or 2 or more \[DropdownMenuItem\]s were detected with the same value Failed assertion: line 882 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72959306/either-zero-or-2-or-more-dropdownmenuitems-were-detected-with-the-same-value-f)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111840/flutter-dropdown-value

Comment: Can you include `selectedfeeling` declaration

Answer (score 0):

It is because, perhaps you are not giving initial value to `selectedfeeling`, which is exist in
`["bad ", "good ", "ok", "sad", "happy"]`
Before calling build method, for example in initState or when declaring `selectedfeeling` just give value to `selectedfeeling`, which exist here
`["bad ", "good ", "ok", "sad", "happy"]`

Comment: how I can give it initial value ?? Can you explain more about your answer that I am a beginner and did not get what you say?

Comment: Yes of course. Look, selectedfeeling must have value non-null. I suggest to learn about stateful widget lifecycle and methods. Another answer above, which you commented “din’t worked, have you another solution?”. Actually there will no another solution. It was exact code what I said in my answer. But body: Center(… should be inside build method. It seems you just din’t put to right place these codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  void initState() {
    selectedfeeling="bad";
  }

body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          items: ["bad ", "good ", "ok", "sad", "happy"]
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("$e"),
                    value: e,
                  ))
              .toList(),
              onChanged: (val) {
                selectedfeeling=val;
              },
          value: selectedfeeling,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: didn't work, Do you have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create nullabe string like selected value like

```dart
  String? selectedfeeling;
```

Now to provide initial value, you must have to provide a value that exists on `items`

```dart
final items = ["bad ", "good ", "ok", "sad", "happy"];
  late String? selectedfeeling = items[1]; //default is good
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          items: items
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("$e"),
                    value: e,
                  ))
              .toList(),
          onChanged: (val) {},
          value: selectedfeeling,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It didn't work when I try to copy and paste your comment and restart the app which requires me to (debug. dart) and there will be a yellow color on the phrase "throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>["

Comment: do a `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: thank you for your reply but it didn't work!! I will try to read more about dropdown button

Comment: Glad to help, you can check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

This error is normally caused when the selected item is not getting matched with the items you passed in the dropdown. So, Either you can assign the first item from the list or you can pass a hint

```dart
List<String> dropDownListItems = ["bad ", "good ", "ok", "sad", "happy"];
String? selectedItem;


Option 1:

body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          items: dropDownListItems
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("$e"),
                    value: e,
                  ))
              .toList(),
             onChanged: (String? val) {
                  setState(() {
                       selectedfeeling = val!;
                   });,
          }
           value: selectedfeeling ?? dropDownListItems.first,
        ),
      ),



Option 2:


body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          items: dropDownListItems
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("$e"),
                    value: e,
                  ))
              .toList(),
         onChanged: (String? val) {
              setState(() {
                 selectedfeeling = val;
               });,
           }
          hint: Text("Choose an item"),
          value: selectedfeeling,
        ),
      ),
```